# No more icons on the Windows 7 Desktop

Tags: windows-7, desktop, icons

I'm visiting my father-in-law, and he asked me to solve a problem he has with his Windows 7. Since 1 or 2 weeks, all the icons that were present on his desktop disappeared (even the trash, or computer icon). He was not able to say what happened that may explain this behavior (software installation, problem...).

After several tests, investigations, here is what I found:

First, on the explorer, I see all the content of the desktop in the `Favoris > Bureau` (i.e. `Favorites > Desktop`) it's maybe important to say that the Windows 7 runs in french. When I right-click on this `Bureau` link, then properties, it says that the target directory is `C:\Users\xxx\Desktop`. However, if I browse the disk, I can go to the `C:\Utilisateurs\xxx\Bureau` (the french version of the same directory), but this directory is empty.

Another strange thing is that I tried to use [RogueKiller](http://tigzy.geekstogo.com/roguekiller.php) application (an application that detects malwares). The prescan completes, then when I run the scan, the icons reappears on the Desktop (but `C:\Users\xxx\Desktop` is still empty). Unfortunately, after a reboot, everything is gone again (but reappears if I run the scan again).

Do you have any idea to solve this problem?

Comment: Not sure if this will help, but there are two desktop directories that are merged in what you see on the screen.  The US versions are typically `C:\Users\username\Desktop` and `C:\Users\Public\Desktop`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe its a dumb question by me but: Is this option checked?

[image]

Comment: I can't tell if you are right or wrong. When I looked at this option, it was checked. I unchecked and rechecked it, then rebooted it. The icons were there, so maybe it was indeed the problem ? I feel really dumb if it's really the case :) I lost time in the configuration management options, but nothing was related to the icons. Anyway, thanks a lot.