# Entire Desktop Deleted

Tags: windows-7, laptop, desktop

I have a question, and I am sorry if I don't perfectly articulate it and have any sort of propriety in doing so--I am frantic, right now! In my "downloads" folder, I had a desktop icon that I didn't find necessary being there. So, I deleted it. Now, I have lost all of my files on my desktop, most notably my transfer letter to RPI. I tried to do a system restore, but it had no effect. What should I do?

Comment: open a command prompt and try running the following line. "start shell:RecycleBinFolder" without the quotes. This should open your recycling bin. See if it is in there and click restore. or hold down the windows key + r to open a run box and insert the above without the leaving "start " portion.

Comment: You only deleted '1' icon from the 'downloads folder' and then a 'bunch of icons' from your desktop disappeared? Is this correct?

Comment: I did that, but there wasn't any desktop icon in it to restore.

Comment: Yes, I lost icons and files alike.

Comment: if you type "cd %userprofile%\desktop" in the command prompt what do you get?

Comment: @EMACK Did you maybe uncheck [this option](http://superuser.com/questions/524122/no-more-icons-on-the-windows-7-desktop/524124#524124) by accident?

Comment: @PhillipR. It said that it didn't recognize that command.

Comment: "cd %userprofile%\desktop" Misstyped it before sorry. If it changes to the directory do a dir and see if your files are listed.

Comment: I would right click on your desktop, click view from the drop down menu, and see if show icons was accidently unchecked. You never know.

Comment: @nixda No, I didn't do that. I even tried to search for one of the files I specifically deleted, but the computer couldn't find it.

Comment: @PhillipR. When I typed that in it said, "The system cannot find the path specified."

Comment: You might need to use something like the following to try and recover the directory listed. http://download.cnet.com/Easeus-Data-Recovery-Wizard-Free-Edition/3000-2248_4-75184619.html This program lets you recover up to 1gb of data for free. Goto easeus.com to see how to use it properly. I am guessing you deleted your desktop and the restore removed it completely.

Comment: I already tried that; it was checked.

Comment: go to start, type 'desktop' in search box, hit enter. Let's at least verify if the icons are gone for starters.

Comment: I just tried that: none of the files that I lost showed up.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is that the desktop folder was hidden for some reason.

start > c: drive > Users > your user name > and see if the desktop folder is visible. if it is, on the top left of the screen there's a drop down list that says 'organize' > folder and search options > view tab > show all hidden files and folders.

Comment: Is it possible it was something called desktop.ini?