# Deleted desktop folder in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, desktop

My entire Desktop folder has been accidentally deleted while I tried to execute an uninstaller for a free software (Pencil) which was lying on my Desktop.

I double clicked the uninstaller and a popup message came up which I ássumed as a standard prompt to confirm un-installation and clicked OK/Yes in a hurry. This started deleting each one of the files/folders from my desktop right in front of my eyes.

Before I could react, all the files were gone from the Desktop and I was left with just the Recycle Bin folder on the Desktop. In fact the folder 'Desktop' is also gone now.

This is on my home laptop which I do not use very often but is shared by others in my family who put their documents on the Desktop directly most of the times.

I have read thoroughly in the last one hour on this topic and did google but cannot find anything relevant to my situation.

I have already checked the items below:

1. Checked the Recycle Bin and arranged contents by 'Date Deleted' and the recent most entry is from 4 day ago
2. Right clicked on the empty desktop -> View -> Show Desktop Icons. This option is enabled already and I can see the Recycle Bin folder icon on the desktop
3. Each time I open the Explorer, I get an popup alert as below saying "... /Deskop is unavailable".

I checked the Home folder (my username is Home - %userprofile%) and looked into its properties, but unfortunately it doesn't have previous versions so that I could get my Desktop folder along with its contents from a previous version of the parent folder Home.

I do not know what to do now, any ideas? I am trying to avoid restarting my laptop thinking that restarting may convert this problem into a unsolvable one. Please help!

Comment: Also note, I have already tried all the steps on [this](https://superuser.com/questions/526015/entire-desktop-deleted)  thread, but it did not help

Comment: If the files were important, you'll have kept back-ups, so restore from there. If other users had their own accounts, their desktops should be unaffected. Otherwise, you will need to try undelete/recovery software: you should do nothing (or as little as possible) before attempting to use it, and you'll need an external disc to save any recovered files, preferably running the software from there.

Comment: You can use an application like this to restore recently deleted files in NTFS.

http://kickassundelete.sourceforge.net/

However this relies on the file system journal. If you need to do a deeper level scan you can use

TestDisk
https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk

But it's unlikely then the data will be accompanied with directory information.

Comment: If data recovery software of your choice, isn't having any luck, then the data is gone.

Answer (score 0):

Recovery program is what I used when I deleted Windows 10 Desktop in an early version of Windows 10.  I cannot recommend System Restore in Windows 10. Doing a repeat test it only restored folders & shortcuts and PROGRAMS.  If you have many programs on Desktop you are in luck.